# Maven - Run JUnit Testsuite in module

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit4

I have 3 Projects:

- ParentProj (parent of A+B)
- ProjA (is a module of ParentProj, contains sources)
- ProjB (is a module of ParentProj, contains sources and tests)

Build order is: 1. ParentProj, 2. ProjA, 3. ProjB (could not be changed!)

I want to tell maven to execute a TestSuite that is located in ProjB.
If I run the build with this command: `mvn clean -e test -Dtest=AllServiceTests`, the build will fail because maven could not find the "AllServiceTests"-class in ProjA, which is build before ProjB.

Is there any solution for this problem? (Changing the build order is no solution)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found the solution:

```
clean install test -Dtest=myTestSuite -DfailIfNoTests=false
```

`-DfailIfNoTests=false` will force maven to continue with the build if ProjA contains no Test classes.

That finally fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into the `--also-make` and `--projects` options?

```
$ mvn --help

usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]

Options:
 -am,--also-make                        If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects required by the
                                        list

 -pl,--projects <arg>                   Comma-delimited list of specified
                                        reactor projects to build instead
                                        of all projects. A project can be
                                        specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                                        or by its relative path.
```

Then I suppose this might work:

```
mvn clean test -pl ProjB -am -Dtest=AllServiceTests
```

Please post back and let us know if that works!  I'm really curious. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution is to change to the ProjB directory and execute your command line there.

Comment: Well, that is no solution, because the nighlty build is done on a Bamboo Server and not on my local command line ;-)